# Recycler view doesn't scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I was previously tested my app on few devices. Genymotion (nexus 4 api 16), samsung i9500 (api 21), samsung i8190 (api 16), nexus 9 (api 23), all worked. But today i tried test app on samsung i8262 (api 16), and meet not working scroll in all recycler views in my app. Most of xml's with recycler view has it as root and single element. I am not watching cause of this problem. Did somebody meet same thing?

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {

    int currentLastArticle = 0;
    int count;
    ArrayList<Article> news = new ArrayList<>();

    View view;
    RecyclerView rv;
    LinearLayoutManager llm;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view, container, false);

        view.setPadding(0, Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(89), 0, 0);

        rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        llm = new LinearLayoutManager(activity);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rv.addItemDecoration(new Divider(activity));
        rv.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerScrollListener(llm) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
                new GetNewsTask().execute(20, currentLastArticle+=20);
            }
        });

        new GetNewsTask().execute(20, currentLastArticle);

        return view;
    }

    class NewsRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public NewsRecyclerAdapter(Context context) {
            inflater = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new NewsVH(inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_item, parent, false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            ((NewsVH)holder).set(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return news.size();
        }

        private class NewsVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            Text title;
            Text time;
            ImageView image;
            View itemView;

            public NewsVH(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                this.itemView = itemView;
                itemView.setPadding(
                        Decorator.getWidthBasedOnIPhone640(8),
                        Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(8),
                        Decorator.getWidthBasedOnIPhone640(8),
                        Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(8)
                );
                init(itemView);
            }

            private void init(View view) {
                title = (Text) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                title.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(24));
                Decorator.setMargins(title, 0, 8, 0, 0);
                time = (Text) view.findViewById(R.id.time);
                time.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(20));
                time.setTextStyle(font.font133l);
                image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
                image.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
                Decorator.setSquareSizeAndMargins(image, 176, 0, 0, 8, 8);
            }

            public void set(final int position) {
                Article article = news.get(position);
                title.setText(article.title());
                time.setText(article.time());
                String image = article.files().length == 0 ? "null" : article.files()[0].url480();
                ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(image, this.image, Decorator.getImageOptions(svg.zelen.drawable()));
                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ArticleFragment fragment = new ArticleFragment();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putParcelable(getString(R.string.article), news.get(position));
                        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                        activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .beginTransaction()
                                .addToBackStack(Flags.CATALOG_BACKSTACK)
                                .replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getCanonicalName())
                                .commit();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    class GetNewsTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, String, JSONArray> {

        int lowTreshold;
        int highTreshold;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            ((ProgressSwitcher)activity).showProgress();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            lowTreshold = params[1];
            highTreshold = params[0];

            String newsString = Web.httpGet(
                    Web.url.domain +
                            Web.url.content +
                            "/" +
                            highTreshold +
                            "/" +
                            lowTreshold
            );

            JSONArray jNewsArray = new JSONArray();

            try {
                JSONObject jNews = new JSONObject(newsString);
                jNewsArray = jNews.getJSONArray("content");
                count = jNews.getInt("count");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return jNewsArray;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jArray) {
            ((ProgressSwitcher)activity).hideProgress();
            int length = jArray.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                try {
                    news.add(new Article(jArray.getJSONObject(i)));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (rv.getAdapter() == null) {
                rv.setAdapter(new NewsRecyclerAdapter(activity));
            } else {
                rv.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for example. R.layout.recyclerview is

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

it is one of many recyclers in my app. They everything aren't scrolling.

Comment: where is your code??

Comment: see update. Sorry for long code piece, but it is the least example. And here all what needed for forming recycler